# How to display a Image in Pop up Window through Window.open

Tags: php, html, window.open

I am trying to display a image in a window pop up using the following javascript

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
```

In the Html code I am using php directory Iterator to find jpeg image and pass it to the javascript. But the pop up window does not open.

```
echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup('.$file_name.');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing extra single quots around the `$filename`

```
echo '<td width="150"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="newPopup(\''.$file_name.'\');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

http://jsbin.com/aqurem/1/edit

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="newPopup('https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse455/12au/projects/project1/students/chantalm/artifact/images/flowers.jpg');">ScreenShot</a>
```

Comment: The image is not from url but stored in a php variable. this code does not work with for this case

Comment: you can add php variable in place of url. it will work.  i just show you an example.

Comment: I tried your code with following statement echo '<td width="150"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="newPopup('.'https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse455/12au/projects/project1/students/chantalm/artifact/images/flowers.jpg'.');">ScreenShot</a></td>'; But still pop up is not working

Comment: image will show when you give whole path including http not by the directory path

Comment: I wrote the complete path. In comments they are not coming correct